# Anychart date/time is not correct

Tags: anychart

I made a webpage what is displaying an AnyChart table.
The problem is the displayed clock is always 3 hours late.
On the following picture the mouse is on a point with the ['2020-08-31 20:12:25 ',29.7,97.4,0.8,0,5.2,9.5,0,30.5,0] data.

[image]

How can I correct the timezone?
The anychart.format.inputLocale('en-gb');
anychart.format.outputLocale('en-us'); lines not changed on the timezone nothing.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

As a default, the chart applies the local timezone offset. If you want to avoid it, you can apply the dateTime pattern manually and the chart will parse the dateTime values as is. For details, [check the sample](https://playground.anychart.com/UmeE1Icj) and pay attention to line 3.

Comment: Answers should include the relevant information in the answer itself.